# How do I change the default editor for a python file?

Tags: python, windows, ide

When I right-click on a .py file, I am given the option to "Edit with IDLE". How can I replace IDLE with another IDE, such as PyCharm? ie when I right-click on any .py file, I would like there to be the option to "Edit with PyCharm".

I am using Windows by the way.

Comment: which version of windows? 3.1, 95, ..., xp, vista, 7?

Comment: I'm using Windows 8. Sorry for not specifying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "Edit with IDLE" option is actually placed there by IDLE itself. The thing you could do is just change the default program you want python files to be opened with (by right clicking, choosing "Open with" and choose a default program).

The additional entries in the context menus are specified in the registry. So i think if you want to manually add a "Edit with PyCharm" option you would have to edit the registry yourself. But I wouldn't recommend to do that at all.

Comment: Thanks. I was aware I could change the default program, but I was hoping to actually add a new option to the registry instead. But if doing that isn't simple, then I guess I'll stick to changing the default program.

Comment: Modify or add an `edit` verb in the registry instead of changing `open`. From the command prompt or Explorer, the `open` verb defined by `HKCR\Python.File\shell\open\command` is used to `ShellExecute` a .py file using either python.exe or the new py.exe launcher.

Comment: @eryksun So I opened the Registry Editor, and in HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Python.File\shell I added a new key, "Edit with PyCharm". I have to add a String, but I don't know what to put for its Value Data. I tried something like "C:\Python34\pythonw.exe" "‪C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 3.4.1\bin\pycharm.exe", but that didn't work...

Comment: @AlessandroPower, you can add this using `reg.exe` in an elevated command prompt: `reg add "HKCR\Python.File\shell\Edit with PyCharm\command" /ve /t REG_SZ /d "\"C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 3.4.1\bin\pycharm.exe\" \"%1\""`. The option `/ve` sets the default value for a key.

Comment: Unfortunately, I get an access denied error for both solutions.

Comment: @eryksun Wonderful, it's working now. I totally missed that I had to be in an elevated command prompt. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

Make a .reg file that looks like the following, then run it and re-login to Windows.  Obviously make the path and filename match your desired editor.  Note the escaped slash characters.  Change how it appears in the menu by substituting your desired command name for "Edit."

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\.py\Shell\Edit\command]
@="E:\\Applications\\Dev\\VSCode\\Code.exe \"%1\""
```

Comment: Note that there's a difference between a "default editor" and the default program association (the program that opens the file when the file is double-clicked) in Windows.  The default editor is the program that opens the file when the file is right-clicked and "edit" is selected.  This can be the same as, or different from, the program that opens the file by default [for most file types, the option to edit simply doesn't exist, nor should it].  For example, Python opens .py files on my PC, but when I right-click and "edit" .py files, they open in VSCode.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is intentionally implemented in an inconsistent and byzantine manner to favor Microsoft products, so this will not work for every file type.  Hey, I don't make the rules, but I don't lie about them, either.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have Windows 7/8 and have the program (in this case PyCharm) installed already, you would:

1. Right click any python file (typically ending with .py)
2. Click "Open With"
3. Either select PyCharm or the desired program from the list of programs OR
4. Click Choose Default Program and 'find more options' or 'choose program from list' and find PyCharm in the directory you installed it in and select program

Hope this helps! Be sure to specify if you meant a different OS than Widows.